# Multiple errors when running npm install -g angular-cli command

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I am having multiple errors when l run the command npm install -g angular-cli
am on windows 10 64 bit. Take a look at my log

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\ben\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\ben\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\ben\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\ben\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ben\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Your log says `Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.` Did you?

Comment: Git is installed and in my Path and still its not working. From angular-cli website git is not a prerequisite and I think there is a bug in compression-webpack-plugin.git from git.

Comment: Is this your first install of the angular-cli or have you had an earlier version installed?

Comment: yes its my first installation for angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Git installed on your computer. So, Just double check everything by following these steps. It might help you:

- Download Git from https://git-scm.com/download/win

Having installed Git, you need to add "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" and  "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" (Your Installation Path)  to the system path.(Click start menu=>Edit the system environment variable)

- Reopen Command window **(Important step)**
- Run Path command in cmd window and you should see Git in the path
- Install Cli >npm install -g angular-cli

Comment: l have tried all that to install GIT and setting it in system path and still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

@Bento when you execute path command in your cmd windows, do you get the GIT in your path list?
You should get something like this:
[image]